# Fetched data does not render but it displays in console VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have created a card, which is supposed to be populated with fetched records.

[image]

and my fetch function underneath it.

[image]

The fetch is working fine, as it is displaying in the console, but it is not populating / creating the card.

I think it might be because the html is already read when I call the function, but I believe with the v-if and v-for that shouldn't be an issue and it is going to display whenever there is data to display.

Any ideas of what am doing wrong?

Kind Regards

Comment: please share the code (the relevant parts) as text not as screenshots

Comment: What made you think pasting pictures of the code instead of the code itself is a good idea? How do you expect those who answer to single out the root cause - by commenting the parts of the picture?

Comment: change `.then(function(response){` to  `.then((response)=>{`

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim - > lifesaver. Was that because I was calling an anonymous function?

Comment: Yes because `this` is undefined in that anonymous function which gives you an error saying `cannot read property list of undefined`